# Illegalkeysize exception

Tags: java, cryptography, centos

I am using the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) Java cryptographic algorithm implementation.
I am getting an `IllegalKeySizeException`. To overcome this I have even changed my java security jars (`local_policy.jar` and `US_Export_policy.jar`), but I am still getting the same problem.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this (I am using centos operating system)?

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it runs on some machines but not on others, the cause can be a missing 'unlimited strength policy file' - [found the hint here](http://o-regan.org/2007/08/03/invalidkeyexception-illegal-key-size-issue/). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Some encryption algorithms expect a fixed key size (or a key that is a multiple of, say, 16 bytes). Pad the key with 0 bytes until it's big enough or truncate it accordingly.

Comment: hi Aaron thanks for ur interest!
i am using the same code on different machine with centos..there i havnt came across such exception...padding the key with 0 will result change in the code...what i want to know is why is this happening even if i have changed the security .jar's of java on current machine..

Comment: Maybe a bug was fixed and the key size is now checked. Make sure you use the exact same version of Java and all JARs on all machines.